# ASP.Net Ajax - PageMethods Synchronous call and retrieval of results

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax, pagemethods, synchronous

**How to ASP.Net Ajax - PageMethods Synchronous call and retrieval of results ?**

Currently i am doing following **async** call and working with data :

```
function checkName(name) {
     PageMethods.IsAvailable(name, onSuccess);
}

function onSuccess(result, context, method) {
    //... do something with result ....
}
```

How can i do same **synchronously with result**?

Comment: did you tried any solution about it ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

IMHO this is not possible with ASP.NET AJAX because the generated wrappers use async calls. By the way you could use jQuery to [call the PageMethod](http://encosia.com/2008/05/29/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/) where it is a matter of setting `async: false`.

Comment: What's about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6700303/any-way-to-do-a-synchronous-pagemethods-call ?