# Any way to do a synchronous PageMethods call?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, asynchronous, pagemethods

I'm trying to do this:

```
function DelBatch()
{var userInfo = get_cookie("UserInfo");
PageMethods.DeleteBatchJSWM(userInfo, function(result)
                                          {window.location = "BatchOperations.aspx";});
}
```

But it still runs asynchronously. I need the browser to actually wait until my code-behind is finished executing, then it can be refreshed

There's a listbox loaded with values that were just deleted from the database, they shouldn't be visible. Problem I have is the window location refreshes before the code-behind is executed, and nothing seems like it was deleted to the user.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Call it using jQuery ajax instead? It features an option (`async`) where you can select sync/async mode: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

This excellent article tells you how best to call PageMethods from jQuery: http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/

Essentially, all you will need to do is this:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  async: false,
  url: "yourpage.aspx/DeleteBatchJSWM",
  data: "{ put json representation of userInfo here }",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(msg) {
    window.location = "BatchOperations.aspx";
  }
});
```

Look at [Crockford's JSON stringify](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js) for a json formatting solution.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to avoid using jQuery, a work around would be to use another PageMethod in which you check the status of the operation using the javascript `setInterval` function. It is a little messy, but it does the job if you want zero jQuery and it mimics the synchronicity you seek. I use it for large operations in which I want to update a progress bar to the client or something. Here would be an example of how you would do this given what code you posted:

```
function DelBatch()
{

        var userInfo = get_cookie("UserInfo");
        PageMethods.DeleteBatchJSWM(userInfo, function(result) {window.location = "BatchOperations.aspx";});

        var status;

    //Check to see if it has completed every second
        var myInterval = setInterval(function ()
        {
            PageMethods.CheckDeleteBatchStatus(OnSuccess);
                if (status == "Finished")
                {
                    clearInterval(myInterval);
                        //Finished Deleting. Call your window refresh here
                WindowRefresh(); 
                }
        }, 1000);


        function OnSuccess(result)
        {
            status = result;
        }
}
```

**Code Behind:**

```
[WebMethod]
public static string CheckDeleteBatchStatus()
{
    string status = GetDeleteBatchStatus(); //some function to get the status of your operation
    return status;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I came across this site:

http://abhijit-j-shetty.blogspot.com/2011/04/aspnet-ajax-calling-pagemethods.html

that had a great method for handling Synchronous PageMethod calls.

The javascript code is as follows:

```
// Make sure page methods operate synchronously
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.original_open = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
    XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function (method, url, async, user, password) {

    async = false;

    var eventArgs = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);

    var q = 0;
    return this.original_open.apply(this, eventArgs);
}

// Make a generic WebMethod caller:
function WebMethodCall(FunctionName, callingobj) {
    var OnSuccess = function (result, userContext, methodName) {
        callingobj.push(result);
    }

    var OnFailure = function (error, userContext, methodName) {
        callingobj.push(error.get_message());
    }

    PageMethods[FunctionName](OnSuccess, OnFailure);

}

// OK, this is kludgy, but here goes. In order to have a synchronous PageMethod call
// we need an object that persists in the namespace to stuff the result value into (like an array)
// Essentially I'm emulating a ByRef call.

// ThisResult is an empty list. The WebMethodCall function sticks a value into that list.
// The code that makes the PageMethods get called synchronously is in Common.js

// Use the functions
var ThisResult = []; // This must be of a type which persists in the namespace
WebMethodCall('HelloWorld', ThisResult);
return ThisResult[0];
```

Comment: It occurs to me that this would be better if it were able to handle arbitrary arguments to the WebMethodCall function, but I don't know how to do that yet.

Answer (score 1):

[Using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6700335) was [first recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1957636) back in 2009.

Another (extremely verbose) option is implementing a synchronous WebRequestExecutor as shown [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/rashid/archive/2007/07/04/SJAX-Call.aspx) (2007-07-04), and perfected [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20130219024005/http://www.ridgway.co.za/archive/2007/10/30/using-synchronous-asp.net-ajax-web-service-calls-and-scriptaculous-to.aspx) (2007-10-30). The gist of the technique is to copy the ASP.NET AJAX Sys.Net.XMLHttpExecutor as a new class named Sys.Net.XMLHttpSyncExecutor and change the call to `xmlHttpRequest.open` to pass `false` as the last parameter to force synchronous operation.

The synchronous executor can be plugged into all requests using [WebRequestManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397494.aspx) like this:

```
Sys.Net.WebRequestManager.set_defaultExecutorType('Sys.Net.XMLHttpSyncExecutor');
```

or you may want to switch it up per-request [just before it is invoked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397421.aspx):

```
Sys.Net.WebRequestManager.add_invokingRequest(function(sender, args) {
 if (iFeelLikeRunningThisRequestSynchronously) {
  args.get_webRequest().set_executor(new Sys.Net.XMLHttpSyncExecutor());
}});
```

[This discussion](http://forums.asp.net/t/925426.aspx) is the source for most of these links and a few more.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this, that lets you call a PageMethod synchronously. It also will just return the result of the method, and throw an error that can be caught in a try/catch block, so you don't need to worry about supplying onSuccess and onError functions.

```
function synchronusPageMethod(method) {

    XMLHttpRequest.prototype.original_open = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;

    XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function (method, url, async, user, password) {
        async = false;

        var eventArgs = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);

        return this.original_open.apply(this, eventArgs);
    };

    var result;
    var error;

    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).slice(1);
    args.push(function (res) {
        result = res;
    });

    args.push(function (err) {
        error = err;
    });

    method.apply(null, args);

    XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.original_open;

    if (error !== undefined) {
        throw error;
    } else {
        return result;
    }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
try {
    var result = synchronusPageMethod(PageMethods.myMethod, argument0, argument1);
    console.log(result);
} catch(error) {
    console.log(error);
}
```