# Make ASP.NET AJAX function call synchronous

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I have an ASP.NET form that calls a web service using ASP.NET AJAX. How do I make the call synchronous?

// test.aspx

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function GetDescription(){
        var code = document.getElementById("<%=txtCode.ClientID%>").value;
        var description = 
            MyNamespace.MyService.GetDescription(
                code, onSuccessGetDescription, null, null);
        return false;
    }

    function OnSuccessGetDescription(result){
        var txtDescription = 
            document.getElementById("<%=txtDescription.ClientID%>");
    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(//function () {

        $('#<%=cmdSave.ClientID%>').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if (Page_ClientValidate()){
                // Populate jQuery.UI dialog box with code and description
                // and then
                $("#confirm-dialog").dialog("open");
            }
        });

    }
</script>

<asp:TextBox ID="txtCode" />
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDescription" />
<asp:Button ID="cmdSave" />
```

// test.aspx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtCode.Attributes["onblur"] = "GetDescription();";
}
```

The answers to this question that I have seen say that I should set the async attribute to false, but I don't see how to do that here.
[ASP.Net Ajax - PageMethods Synchronous call and retrieval of results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1957600/asp-net-ajax-pagemethods-synchronous-call-and-retrieval-of-results) says that it can't be done. I am trying to get a second opinion.

If I can't make the call synchronous, would it be legal to make GetTransaction poll until the OnSuccess function returns? What would be an efficient (i.e. not CPU-intensive) way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[JQuery Asynchronous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133310/how-can-i-get-jquery-to-perform-a-synchronous-rather-than-asynchronous-ajax-re)

```
jQuery.ajax({
url: 'http://example.com/catalog/create/' + targetNode.id + '?name=' + encode(to.inp[0].value),
success: function (result) {
   if (result.isOk == false) alert(result.message);
    },
    async: false
});
```

Comment: I am almost there. When calling a web service method this way, are you expected to parse the result yourself? The responseText is something like:
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>

<string xmlns='http://example.com'>
  Pepsi 2L
</string>

Comment: You can convert on web service site into JSON format. http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/pini_dayan/2009/03/12/convert-objects-to-json-in-c-using-javascriptserializer/     System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer oSerializer = 
         new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
string sJSON = oSerializer.Serialize(object);